# how to logresolve httpd log file to /dev/null and tail it?

Tags: grep, tail

I would like to watch traffic live (httpd log activity) ,

I currently use **tail -f /var/www/access.log**
It works fine , its live, however  just want to convert ip address to hostnames, i dont want to enable it permanently in httpd.conf.

is there a way i can  combine  **tail -f | logresolve access.log > /dev/null**  ?

Thank you, ENglish not my first language.

Answer (score 2):

You've got it *almost* right:

```
tail -f /var/www/access.log | logresolve
```

should work for you. (logresolve, at least as far as I could gather from [the man page](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/logresolve.html), reads from "standard input" and outputs to "standard output", so the above will just feed access.log into it.

Comment: well thanks i remember i did something like that 15 years ago . then thought today tht was too simple and wouldnt work. but why does itw ork if logresolve needs additional parameters after the command? i